# using python and plotly, can't pass string array to text parameter

Tags: python, plotly

(I'm pretty obviously new to programming and to python.)
I want to add some text to a stacked bar chart I'm creating using python and plotly. If I supply the text parameters directly, everything works fine. If I set the text parameters as a list, the text parameter is ignored.

The following works great, and places "A" with the first bar, "B" with the second, "C" with the third.

```
    this_bar = go.Bar(
        x = list_of_people,
        y = y_axis,
        text = ["A", "B", "C"],
        name = 'Bar Chart'
        )
```

The following code doesn't work the same way, and I'm not sure why. It ignores the text parameter altogether (and doesn't place any text with any bars):

```
alphabet = ["A", "B", "C"]
this_bar = go.Bar(
            x = list_of_people,
            y = y_axis,
            text = [alphabet],
            name = 'Bar Chart'
        )
```

Plotly's docs seem to indicate that I should be able to do this, but I must be missing something simple.

> text (string) 
>   default: "" 
>   Sets text elements associated with each (x,y) pair. If a single string, the same string appears over all the data points. If an array of string, the items are mapped in order to the this trace's (x,y) coordinates.(https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar-text)

I'm using Python 3.4 if it matters.

Comment: you need `text = alphabet`. Now you create `text = [  ["A", "B", "C"] ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
text = alphabet
```

When you do

```
alphabet = ["A", "B", "C"]
text = [ alphabet ]
```

then you get 2-dimensional list (list inside list)

```
text = [ ["A", "B", "C"] ]
```

Comment: Wow. I mentioned I'm a beginner, right? Ha! I appreciate your help--looking at all of the examples and trying many different things, I still didn't figure this out. Sigh.